# Как установить данные в state при первом рендере?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

Есть компонент, в при загрузке страницы в его методе `componentDidMount` я делаю get-запрос на сервер:

```
componentDidMount: function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/adress',
            data: data_storage,
            success: function (data_storage) {
                this.setState({data_storage: data_storage});
            }.bind(this),
            beforeSend: function () {
                this.setState({loading: true});
            }.bind(this)
        });
 },
```

Данные принимаю и устанавливаю их в `state` сразу. Далее они мне понадобятся для формирования компонента(это происходит с помощью методов на ходу и зависит от полученных данных). Вот тут и проблема, что при первом рендере `data_storage` является undefined  и метод, который работает с этим параметром отваливается.НО если я уберу метод, то в консоль логе вижу,что компонент рендерится несколько раз-первый без `data_storage`, а второй с ним. В чем моя ошибка? Как мне это дело прописать так, чтобы он при первом рендере уже имел информацию и не ругался?

Comment: Ну а как вы хотели, сначала компонент рендерится, а потом у вас событие изменения приходит, и он обновляет данные. Что не так? Логика абсолютно верная. Правда использовать jquery когда работаешь с reactом странное дело. Для ajax лучше использовать axios, и такие вещи надо делать в экшенах (если вы работаете в redux). Вы можете в render методе сделать условие, по которому при `data_storage` в `undefined` возвращать `null`, но компонент все равно отрендерется, в этом вся суть.

Comment: Ну на крайняк, вы можете запустить рендер компонента только когда у вас появятся данные, но это нужно делать выше по иерархии. Без данных в компоненте вы можете ничего не делать, тогда и падать нечему будет)

Comment: какие изменения?у меня есть компонент, который состоит из компонентов поменьше. их количество может отличаться в зависимости от данных, полученных с сервера. мне нужно перед самой отрисовкой забрать данные и на их основе отрисовать компоненты. если вы говорите,что все верно,выходит надо воспользоваться другим методом, а не DidMount?  не работаю в redux.  Почему использование jquery-странное дело?

Comment: Про jquery, лучше использовать целенаправленные вещи, а не сбор мусорки из старого дева (у каждого свои предпочтения, но я советую избавиться от этого, плохие манеры). А про инициализацию, просто условие ставьте, что если у вас не пришли ещё данные просто в render методе null возвращайте. Когда они у вас подтянутся все сработает как надо, и падать будет нечему

Comment: сделал проверку.заработало как надо и больше не выпадает.спасибо зп одсказку. вас не затруднит продублировать комментарий в качестве ответа?я его выберу как ответ на вопрос и закрою топик?
насчет инструментов, axios посмотрел. интересная вещь, какие еще есть инстересные инструменты для react?

Comment: Сложно сказать, я не знаю что вы используете :) А так, в зависимости от того, какого рода приложения вы пытаетесь построить, перенос состояния в `redux` это хорошо, но не всегда нужно. А остальное зависит от `best practice`, который идет от опыта

Comment: в каких случаях следует использовать flux или redux?

Comment: Я в принципе почти везде использую, где появляется более сложная архитектура в состояниях. Это дает прозрачность для стороны компонентов, они лишь работают с какими-то данными. + тестировать состояния и после событий очень удобно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил краткий пример работающего кода с ожиданием данных.

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      myData: undefined
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      this.setState({
        myData: {
          param1: 'param1',
          param2: 'param2',
          param3: 'param3',
        }
      })
    }.bind(this), 4000);
  }

  render () {
    if (!this.state.myData) {
      return <div>NO DATA</div>
    }

    return <div>
      Test application
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, window.root)
```

Проверить работу **[можно тут](http://codepen.io/bustexz/pen/OpLgyP)**

Comment: Тут нужно ещё удалять timeout - при componentWillUnmount()...

иначе может произойти ситуация когда компонент удалили, а он пытается сменить состояние...

Comment: @xFloooo верно подмечено